# Microsoft Graph Security sample event data, or sample event generator?

Tags: microsoft-graph-security

I would like to check if anyone is aware of sample events, or built-in native sample event generator, for any of the below integrations?

- Azure Security Center
- Azure Active Directory Identity Protection*
- Microsoft Cloud App Security
- Microsoft Defender Advanced Threat Protection*
- Azure Advanced Threat Protection*
- Office 365*
- Azure Information Protection

I have collected a few sample events in my own test tenant, but need much more to fully test my app.

I have looked across the various potential sources, and besides schema, I can't seem to find comprehensive sample event data, or a way in of the integrations above to generate any or random events with dummy data.